# Android textview on imageview

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to place an `TextView` on a `ImageView` in the bottom center of the `RelativeLayout`. 
I am able to place the `TextView`in the center but not able to place it in the bottom .
Can anyone guide me.
here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#000000">
   </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text98"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"            
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"        
            android:text="LAST"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add this for textview `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eventimage"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the textView use the following attributes `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and add `android:alignParentBottom=true"`. Also look at the relative layout options to understand how to work with it.

Comment: thanks . How can i use android:layout_marginBottom independent of all screens ?

Comment: what do you mean independent of all screens, you can use dp, if you are referring to the screen densities.

Comment: As in I want to place the textView 20% from bottom on all screen sizes . How do i achieve that ? I can't just give a number .

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like

```
android:layout_alignBaseline (@id/eventimage);
```

and add some padding on the bottom later

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_alignParentBottom` to move the control to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventimage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#000000">
   </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text98"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"          
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"        
            android:text="LAST"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eventimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#000000">
       </ImageView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text98"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"            
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"        
                android:text="LAST"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your TextView:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/eventimage"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#000000">
   </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text98"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alignBottom="@+id/eventimage"            
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"        
        android:text="LAST"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This layout works according to your requirement .by setting the **gravity bottom** of the linear layout ,its chilld view is automatically aligned at center- bottom position

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
      android:gravity="bottom">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text98"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="LAST"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/
       >

</LinearLayout>
```